# CSS markup to have one fixed div with a scrollable adjacent div

Tags: html, css

I have some basic markup like this:

```
 <body>
    <div id="static-container">
       <p id="do-not-move">Example.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="scroll-container"></div>
 </body>
```

Basically, I want the `static-container` to remain fixed, and never move. The `scroll-container` will have content added to it and will be scrollable, but it should always be physically below the `static-container`, and scrolling should never overlap into `static-container`, I can put `position: fixed` in the `static-container` but the `scroll-container` still manages to scroll into it.

Comment: Does `#static-container` have a fixed height?

Comment: It doesn't, but I can easily add one if it'll help.

Comment: went ahead and answered for both scenarios. will one of those work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
body,html {height:100vh;}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
#static-container {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
#scroll-container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
    <div id="static-container">
       <p id="do-not-move">Example.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="scroll-container"><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p></div>
```

Comment: The problem is the content in example scrolls along with the rest of the content. I don't want it to scroll, only the content in the red div should be scrollable, but always below the fixed content above.

Answer (score 0):

Make the static-container div position fixed and some height.
Give some height to scroll-div and scroll-y: scroll

HTML:

```
        <div id="static-container">
           <p id="do-not-move">Example.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="scroll-container">
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum ut ipsum rutrum, commodo felis ac, mattis justo. Vivamus feugiat urna ac est efficitur blandit. Maecenas vestibulum turpis ante, nec pharetra enim rutrum vitae. Fusce pharetra felis fringilla tincidunt porta. Praesent porttitor posuere erat eu viverra. 
          </p>
          <p>
          Aliquam lacus nisl, dictum non ultricies eget, malesuada et nisi. Maecenas felis turpis, blandit at leo id, efficitur pellentesque velit. Morbi sapien augue, sagittis eget dictum a, bibendum ut dui. Morbi vulputate tempor tortor, id blandit lorem vulputate id. In blandit nibh sit amet ante vestibulum volutpat. 
          </p>
          <p>
          Nam quis nisi magna. Sed lacinia id quam eget gravida. Donec vitae luctus leo. Sed efficitur sapien eu elit tincidunt, eu vehicula felis rutrum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
          </p>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #static-container{background-color:#333;color:#FFF;height:30px; padding:10px 0; postion:fixed; top:0; text-align:center; width:500px}
    #scroll-container{background-color:#ccc;height:200px;  position:relative;  overflow-y:scroll; padding:0 10px;  width:480px}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avinashMaddy/teck3yyg/2/)